# Deployment to ECS takes a lot of time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have a couple of next.js apps on AWS Elastic Container Service.

I'm using CodePipeline in order to automate the CI/CD process (source is Github, build step is CodeBuild). Everything works perfectly except the "Deploy" step that takes way too much (approx. 10 minutes). I am hosting the docker image on AWS ECR.

What I already tried:

1. I tried to increase the tasks number.
2. I tried a stronger EC2
   instance.
3. I tried to change the target group's Deregistration delay
   from 300 secs to 5 secs.
4. I tried to change Healthy threshold in
   target group from 5 to 2. and the Interval to 5 seconds as well.

Do you have any idea what could cause it? I usually use Heroku but unfortunately I need to host a socket web-api and I need it to be on the same machine for better performance.

Here are some logs:
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: How big is the container? Maybe the download is taking a long time or there's a 3rd party package that is bigger than you think?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The container weighs 850mb but it's on ECR so I don't think it should take that amount of time. Also when I check the logs, I can see that it takes approx 10 seconds to download and push. The deploying to ECR is the most time consuming process :[

Comment: What do the logs for the Deploy step say? There are a number of different steps within deploying ECS, and narrowing down which step is slow during the ECS deployment would be helpful.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I uploaded an image with the last logs to the question